# Asymptotic approximation $I(\lambda) = \int \frac{h(x)}{(h(x) + \lambda |x|^k)^2}\,dx$

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose we have the integral
$$
I(\lambda) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{h(x)}{(h(x) + \lambda |x|^k)^2}\,dx,\qquad \lambda > 0,
$$
with $h(x)$ the squared modulus of the characteristic function/Fourier transform of a square-integrable probability density. So $h(x)$ is non-negative, bounded above by one, square-integrable, $h(0) = 1$, etc. We can take $k \geq 2$.

Is there a natural asymptotic approximation for $I(\lambda)$ as $\lambda \to 0$?

Comment: Pardon me if I am asking a foolish question. Do you wish to know a general asymptotic expansion for _any_ PDF? I feel that particular remarks may be given for specific distributions, but I do not know of any means to establish a formula for the general distribution. That, however, may be solely a product of my limited knowledge.

Comment: That is a reasonable question. I wouldn't anticipate a general result to hold for any PDF, but I suspect one might hold that depends on some property of h (e.g. the behavior of h(x) as |x| → ∞)

Specifically, if you divide top and bottom by h(x)², the denominator is like a continuous approximation of an indicator, so it "feels" like we're integrating 1/h(x) over a neighborhood of the origin, the radius determined by λ. But I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: Ah, your viewpoint is quite refreshing. I should find that what you have described is reminiscent of a Green's function (when $L=\text{id}$) from PDEs or a Dirac delta function $\delta$. I confess that when I originally read your post, I did not see the stipulation that $k\geq 2$. I'm working on mulling over some of my thoughts. I'll probably post it into the answer box as it is too long for a comment.

Comment: My advice: Start with $h$ associated with a general Gaussian distribution and see if that suggests anything.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to plot the integral in question on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1r1fq7pme4). Although I do not believe that $h(x) = x^2$ makes all that much sense in the context of a probability density function, I was first curious to examine the case when $h(x) = x^2$ and $k = 2$.

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{h(x)}{(h(x) + \lambda|x|^k)^2} dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1 + \lambda)^2|x|^{4}} dx \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1 + \lambda)^2|x|^{4}} dx \\
& = \frac{2}{(1 + \lambda)^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}} dx
\end{align}

This last integral clearly does not converge as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} \to \infty$. I would like to believe, furthermore, that such behavior will be avoided when $h(x) < 1 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, but I am not certain of it. (I think one may also need to ensure that the PDF has only finite support. The conditions together would probably be sufficient but not necessary for the integral to exist.)

I guess that it would be prudent to consider the most common distribution

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left({\frac{-1}{2} \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\right)
$$

I am just interested in the shape of the function, so I shall simplify it to

$$
f(x) = \exp \left({\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)
$$

Then, taking a second order Taylor approximation

$$
f(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}
$$

we find that it is only really valid in the neighborhood $\left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$. (Note I haven't considered the error bound rigorously, I only examine it graphically.)

We can then restrict the support of the integrand to that interval and note that

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{1 - x^2} dx$$

converges (and can be thought of as a constant multiple of an arctangent like integral along the imaginary axis). For the case of the full distribution, we may find an apparent contradiction if we assume uniform convergence and pass the limit inside of the integral.

\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{h(x)}{(h(x) + \lambda|x|^k)^2} dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{\lambda\to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{\left(e^{-\frac{x}{2}} + \lambda|x|^2\right)^2} dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}} dx\\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\frac{x}{2}} dx
\end{align}

But, unfortunately, this last integral fails to converge as well, seemingly invalidating my original hypothesis about boundedness implying well posedness. I would guess that my final question is

> If $h(x)$ is square integrable and decays to $0$ asymptotically, would not the integrand be approximated as $\frac{1}{\lambda |x|^k}$ for sufficiently large $x>x_0$? Further, I feel that the rate at which $\lambda\to 0$ would be important in evaluating the limit. I wonder if the term proportional to $\frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{1}{x^{k-1}}$ could be problematic.

I think the integral would only make sense (for a general PDF) when the domain is finite. I might be grossly mistaken here, but these were my first thoughts. Did this problem appear in a textbook or did you come across it while researching? If the latter is true, I might wish to suggest MathOverflow where you could pose the problem to a specialist.

Comment: The λ seems to have disappeared in your last set of integrals. The integral comes from analyzing a regularization procedure which gives an approximate inverse of the multiplication operator f ↦ √(h)·f. But the exact inverse f ↦ f/√h is "bad" (doesn't exist, is discontinuous, etc). So it makes sense that 1/h is poorly behaved, as that's essentially the original problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry I substituted $\lambda=0$ without bothering to type in the full limit. I see now that you are willing to part with uniform convergence in that passing the limit inside the integrand would contradict the original purpose... Indeed, that does make my "answer" very superfluous. My apologies. Assuming an antiderivative does exist for the integrand $\frac{h(x)}{(h(x) + \lambda |x|^k)^2}$ and is expressable as a function of $\lambda$ must it not diverge to $\infty$ if it is to bear semblance to one of the aforesaid illconditioned PDFs. In my limited opinion, would not any affirmation of

Comment: convergence be only an artifact of pointwise convergence as opposed to a deeper truth about the distribution? I'm reminded of a poorly conditioned integral I found in physics a while ago. I had managed to assign a value to it only to find that it was no longer in line with physical reality. The last thought I have is representing the integral as an analytic function and computing it's value via a residue or applying zeta regularization. In either case, I feel $h(x)$ would have to be rather simple in form. I apologize if I made any typos; I tried writing this on my phone.

Comment: For any $h$, $I(\lambda) \to \infty$ as $\lambda \to 0$; I don't expect this to have a limit. Instead I hope for some relatively simple expression (in terms of $\lambda$) for the behavior in the limit. Maybe $I(\lambda) \approx \int_{-L}^L 1/h(x)\,dx$ for $L = L(\lambda)$ depending on $\lambda$. Then if $L(\lambda)$ is available in closed form and the definite integral can be computed, I have some nice expression for $I(\lambda)$ (approximately).

Comment: Do you have a particular form for $h(x)$ in mind? Otherwise, I agree that the question would probably have a negative answer in the general case. I guess the question would be well posed when $h(x)$ is the reciprocal of a probability density function with the properties you mentioned above. Is your goal to characterize $h$ by examing the rate of growth as lambda collapses to 0?

Comment: $h$ is the squared modulus of the Fourier transform of a square-integrable pdf (or characteristic function of a random variable with that pdf). This implies a lot of regularity about $h$; it is uniformly continuous, integrable, $0 \leq h(x) \leq 1$, and $h(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$, and more.

I don't need to characterize $h$; it is given by the problem. I need to get a handle on $I(\lambda)$ as $\lambda \to 0$. I don't expect to find one universal approximation in terms of $\lambda$, but I suspect there is one that depends on $\lambda$ and the tail of $h$ in a simpleish way.